React: `setSomeState([..., x, ...])` update only applies to particular child element
Sometimes I want a parent element to keep track of the children's state. For example, a state that's a list where each item corresponds to exactly one DOM-child. In my application this is a multi-message LLM-chat window where a websocket accepts tokens and appends them to the response to one of the messages a user had input - e.g. like chatgpt where tokens appear slowly. Usually this should be the last message the user wrote, but due to race conditions or unforeseen future features it could be any.
This situation is similar to this simple variant:
function Child({number, id}) {
    console.log(`render ${number}`);
    return <p key={`number-${id}`}>{number}</p>
}


function Parent() {
  var [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([1,2,7,9]);

  if (numbers[1] !== 10) {
    // update to one item in `numbers`, e.g. as per a websocket message
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNumbers(numbers.slice(0, 1).concat([10]).concat(numbers.slice(2)));
    }, 4000)
  }

  //implicit structure that i-th child should only refresh on state change of `numbers[i]`.
  return numbers.map((number, id) => <Child {...{number, id}}/>);
}

However, setNumbers will trigger render updates of all children, particularly if (semantic) equality of items can't be measured. Is there an elegant design pattern or method to allow for only the appropriate child to be rendered again while keeping the setTimeout (or websocket) in control of the parent?
(This is a question that has been stuck with me for some time - apologies if my way is abuse of React or I plainly don't understanding something)

If you wrap child in React.memo, it’ll work the way you want (I’m ignoring the fact you’ve mutated state in your question). But I’d question as to why you want it to work that way. Is it causing a problem? Please describe the problem you’re having, if so. I’ve noticed your aren’t using keys

Sorry about the keys, it's something I commonly forget, but I updated the OP. I want this because I'd guess all the renders to show the same thing as before are slow? That is, it's also premature optimization since I'm not empirically experiencing slowness, but would guess consistently applying a pattern where only the child gets updated is smart.

Other reasons could be that consecutive renders may mess up user input states the browser had, e.g. the user selecting part of a text, hovers, typed stuff, etc, causing a bad user experience. And Memo uses Object.is, which doesn't work or work well for nested data structures. It seems like a design pattern here could be a parallel list state updateNo that each required refresh render of a child is increases, such that the child can simply check that property useMemo - but this might make the code confusing.

You still didn’t add the key. But from my guess, if you’re experiencing logical errors (messed up states) it’s specifically because you are not applying the keys correctly. The key should be a non-changing value that refers to the component that is being rendered. If the order of elements will 100% never change, you can use the index in the array, but it’s a good practice to avoid doing that. If you are experiencing problems with stateful children being rerendered, this is the cause, it has nothing to do with trying to isolate rerenders more granularly

The key should go on <Child /> instead of on <p/> ? Or on both? And of course, I'd usually use some type of identifier, but didn't have one for this minimal example. I'm not experiencing state issues, I'm just trying to understand how React wouldn't render again all children if numbers changes, but in reality only one item of the array changed, particularly when the items are dictionaries that are semantically the same, but different according to Object.is. And with render again I mean remove (native) DOM nodes and reinsert new ones.

You should almost never care about when react renders. There are certain cases (usually keystroke related) when performance is critical, but most of the time it’s not a concern you should have, especially if you aren’t seeing logical or performance issues. And yes, key goes on the Child (the component that’s being rendered in a loop), not on the content of what’s in the child. This is very important. There are other frameworks that isolate renders and are more performant. But react is good enough most of the time, and you can’t force it to act like those other frameworks

Fair, thanks for your patience to explain!
